# how to get this results for this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2019

Write a SELECT statement that returns these columns from the db1.MyGuitarShop.Products table:

a)  The DateAdded column

b)  A column that uses the CAST function to return the DateAdded column with its date only (year, month, and day)

c)  A column that uses the CAST function to return the DateAdded column with its full time only (hour, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds)

d)  A column that uses the CAST function to return the DateAdded column with just the month and day

This is what I have currently:

```
SELECT
    DateAdded,
    CAST(DateAdded AS decimal(10, 1)) AS AddedDate,
    CAST(DateAdded AS decimal(10)) AS AddedTime,
    CAST(DateAdded AS int) AS AddedChar7
FROM MyGuitarShop.Products;
```

Comment: In the future, you may want to ensure that the title for your post is more descriptive. It will make it easier for people to understand what you are trying to do before looking at the post. For example ... "How can I format a Date column into different formats"

Answer (score 0):

With `CAST` converting to a `DATE` and `TIME` is easy. But the third item is trickier and involves two separate `CASTS`'s, followed by string concatenation.

Something like this shoul do the trick:

> Note that I've subbed in a variable (`@dt`) just to make it simpler to demonstrate the concept.

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME = GETDATE()
SELECT      @dt
        ,   CAST(@dt AS Date) AS AddedDate
        ,   CAST(@dt AS Time) AS AddedTime
        ,   CAST(MONTH(@dt) AS VARCHAR(4)) + CAST(DAY(@dt) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS AddedChar
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/92704)

Answer (score 0):

Another options would be to use `CONVERT` to convert the dates to text. It has the advantage of allowing you to choose a specific format for the results ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

```
SELECT
    DateAdded,
    CONVERT(varchar(128), DateAdded, 111) AS AddedDate,
    CONVERT(varchar(128), DateAdded, 14) AS AddedTime,
    CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, DateAdded) as varchar(2)) + '/' + CAST(DATEPART(DAY, DateAdded) as varchar(2)) AddedChar7
FROM (VALUES
        (GETDATE())
    )Products(DateAdded)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  DateAdded
        ,Cast(DateAdded as date) Cast_YMD --Default for date is YMD
        ,Cast(DateAdded as time) Cast_HMSM -- Default for time is HMSM
        ,CAST(DateAdded as char(6)) Cast_MMDD --The 6 characters in the date field are month(as 3 char name Jan,Feb...) and day(as 2 digit)   
FROM Products
```